# How to implement health check service for Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-services, jasmine, health-monitoring

I have an Angular web app (with a backend in Java SpringBoot).
Need to build a health check (monitoring) service, which tests that all its services are up and running and shows the status.  Let's say it's a sales app, which has services CompanyService, and AccountService with functions like getCompanies(), getAccount(id), updateXXX(), etc. There is something like that on server side (healthz/readyz in Kubernetes).
Is it possible to build that service as a unit test, which calls several other unit tests (testing its individual services) using Jasmine/Karma? How can we integrate that in the application, so the user clicks a button, it runs and returns/displays the result in the app?  If not, what approach would you suggest?
And on stage 2 maybe make it run automatically every minute or so.

Please advise,
Oleg.

Comment: Unit tests are not part of the built application. You can run them locally, while building in pipe, but they are of no use for users accessing your page. Best approach would be to utilize APP_INITIALIZER where you can use this HealthService. It will make sure that you won't see anything before BE services are up

Comment: I will investigate APP_INITIALIZER.  Also someone suggested me to use Cypress instead of Jasmine/Karma to run tests from inside web app. Any idea how to use it for that (call the tests from the app, get results - maybe in JSON or display them), I never used Cypress. Please advise.

Comment: Any better way to implement Angular services health checks? I've heard that can kick the unit tests via Karma, and actually start monitoring them using it: "set the Karma configuration to run in autoWatch mode and use a task scheduler such as cron or Windows Task Scheduler to run the Karma command on a set schedule". I don't have much experience with Karma. And we have most unit tests of those services already written, so if possible, I'd love to use them. Not sure how to kick such health check service from web app & how to call unit tests of those Angular services. Any idea, code samples?

Comment: What I don't understand is, when do you want to make such health check? When the app is up and running on the server and user is accessing it? Or while developing?

Comment: This is a complex (kind of mission critical app), so we need it to be up and running 99.9% of the time, so if something goes wrong, someone should be aware and take action. So during running it mostly, although when we develop it and say deploy some new version or push updates if something goes wrong, would be very useful to know too.

Comment: The point of the unit tests is never to check the live URL. Whatever you are pretending to do with a server in a unit test, it's just mocked. Using Karma/Jasmin for this is just wrong. You either need some standalone monitoring app, or long polling implemented which will do the health check in a given interval

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between Unit tests and a health check/monitoring. As mentioned in the comments, unit tests and integration tests happen before the app is released. You don't want to constantly check the functionality in a live production app, this needs to be done in the build pipeline before deployment.

Health checking, to monitor if your app is still running, is something that *does* need to be done in production.
In case of an Angular app, the health check can simply consist of an external service that calls your app, to see if the HTTP response code returns '200 OK'.

An Angular app is actually static code, Javascript, HTML and CSS, so *if the webserver does it's job, the app will run*, because everything happens in the browser.
So checking if your webserver is still serving up your static page(s) is enough.

To check your backend API(s), a standard way of doing so, is to have a `/health` endpoint that does some backend checks (like check to see if your database can be queried, or if all other backend dependencies are up and running) and returning a status. Many monitoring tools will have the option to test these /health endpoints and alert if something is wrong.